# Should I make separate UIViewController just because a single row is different in layout

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am a very basic SWIFT Xcode programmer. I make small apps.
For last 2 days, I am stuck at a very simple thing and I am sure with your guidance I can quickly make a decision.

I have a UIViewController class as well as an xib
In the layout I have 4 textfields

Now based on a user setting (in another frame user make a choice), I will either have to show 4 textfields ** OR ** 3 textfields and a UISwitch.

Long story short, if user select one option he should see UISwitch and 3  textfields or else 4 textfield. The labels's text also change.

To my limited knowledge, I will make another UIViewController, another XIB file and if user selection allows I will segue to the new UIViewController.

But all this looks so redundant. How do you smart people do this thing?

- (Edit)
  I use size classes in my layout as well as constraints in the visual editor for positioning of elements on the layout. If I change things programmatically, which is one option, how will I manage the layout ?

Please advise.
Show me the right path please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user select first option based on action show or hide the text field or switches, like when user select first option only show three text field and one UIswitch hide fourth text field.

And programatically change text field hint value and also set NSString Tag="first" so that when you want that value at the time of submit button you can apply if condition to tag and on that basis you can get your desired output on each selection.

Comment: Thanks Rajat for your reply. So you are saying that I go to the visual Storyboard and put the UISwitch also over the 4 textfield. I do the alignment like I want in the visual builder and then just in the program HIDE the UISwitch until it is required to be shown ?

Comment: Thanks I am trying it.

Comment: How do I hide an UITextField or UISwitch ? I tried txtRuns.hidden = true with no success

Comment: text.hidden=yes where text is UiTextField same can be used for UISWitch.
when you want to show UITextField use text.hidden=NO;

Comment: Thank you so much, working like a charm. I was thinking 2 days on how to do it and it took you 2 min. I salute you.

Comment: if you will have 4 textfields, make sure to handle the case if onscreen keyboard overrides the 4th textfield especially for iphone 4s.
Simulator by default might not show onscreen keyboard which can be configured.